# MsrpPriceCalculator Exception

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Whenever I go to a page that contains products (Catalog/Product-search/etc.) i get the error exception below; anyone any idea why?

Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $msrpPriceCalculators of Magento\Msrp\Pricing\MsrpPriceCalculator.

```
#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Msrp\Pri...', array(array('msrpPriceCalcula...', NULL, true, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Msrp\Pri...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Msrp\Pri...') called at [vendor/magento/module-msrp/Helper/Data.php:82]
#4 Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data->__construct(&Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context#0000000032fe7dc20000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager#0000000032fe7dde0000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Msrp\Model\Product\Options\Proxy#0000000032fe64570000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Msrp\Model\Msrp#0000000032fe64560000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Msrp\Model\Config#0000000032fe77320000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency#0000000032fe7fec0000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor#0000000032fe7fac0000000012f0273d#, NULL) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#5 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Msrp\Hel...', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context#0000000032fe7dc20000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager#0000000032fe7dde0000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Msrp\Model\Product\Options\Proxy#0000000032fe64570000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Msrp\Model\Msrp#0000000032fe64560000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Msrp\Model\Config#0000000032fe77320000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency#0000000032fe7fec0000000012f0273d#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor#0000000032fe7fac0000000012f0273d#, NULL)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#6 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Msrp\Hel...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Msrp\Hel...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:160]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\Msrp\Hel...'), 'Magento\Msrp\Hel...', NULL, 'msrpData', 'Magento\Msrp\Pri...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\Msrp\Pri...', array(array('saleableItem', 'Magento\Catalog\...', true, NULL), array('quantity', NULL, true, NULL), array('calculator', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('priceCurrency', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('msrpData', 'Magento\Msrp\Hel...', true, NULL), array('config', 'Magento\Msrp\Mod...', true, NULL)), array('saleableItem' => &Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000032fe688d0000000012f0273d#, 'quantity' => 0)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#10 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Msrp\Pri...', array(array('saleableItem', 'Magento\Catalog\...', true, NULL), array('quantity', NULL, true, NULL), array('calculator', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('priceCurrency', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('msrpData', 'Magento\Msrp\Hel...', true, NULL), array('config', 'Magento\Msrp\Mod...', true, NULL)), array('saleableItem' => &Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000032fe688d0000000012f0273d#, 'quantity' => 0)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#11 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Msrp\Pri...', array('saleableItem' => &Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000032fe688d0000000012f0273d#, 'quantity' => 0)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Msrp\Pri...', array('saleableItem' => &Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000032fe688d0000000012f0273d#, 'quantity' => 0)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Price/Factory.php:47]
#13 Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Factory->create(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000032fe688d0000000012f0273d#, 'Magento\Msrp\Pri...', 0) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Price/Collection.php:139]
#14 Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Collection->get('msrp_price') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Price/Collection.php:94]
#15 Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Collection->current() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/BasePrice.php:31]
#16 Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\BasePrice->getValue() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/FinalPrice.php:44]
#17 Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice->getValue() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Price/AbstractPrice.php:101]
#18 Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\AbstractPrice->getAmount() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php:156]
#19 Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox->hasSpecialPrice() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox/Interceptor.php:37]
#20 Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox\Interceptor->hasSpecialPrice() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml:24]
#21 include('/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox\Interceptor#0000000032fe6b9c0000000012f0273d#, '/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox/Interceptor.php:271]
#24 Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox\Interceptor->fetchView('/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/PriceBox.php:69]
#26 Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php:71]
#27 Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox/Interceptor.php:583]
#29 Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox\Interceptor->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render.php:98]
#30 Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render->render('final_price', &Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000032fe688d0000000012f0273d#, array('include_containe...' => true, 'display_minimal_...' => true, 'zone' => 'item_list', 'list_category_pa...' => true)) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:387]
#31 Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->getProductPrice(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000032fe688d0000000012f0273d#) called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php:180]
#32 Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->getProductPrice(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#0000000032fe688d0000000012f0273d#) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml:72]
#33 include('/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor#0000000032fe780d0000000012f0273d#, '/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php:557]
#36 Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->fetchView('/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php:882]
#39 Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('category.product...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('category.product...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('category.product...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('category.product...', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('category.product...', true) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:508]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('product_list') called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Category/View.php:100]
#46 Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View->getProductListHtml() called at [app/code/Riff/UCW/view/frontend/templates/category/products.phtml:8]
#47 include('/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Riff\UCW\Block\Category\View#0000000032fe7b990000000012f0273d#, '/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/mnt/c/wamp64/ww...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('customProducts') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('customProducts') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('customProducts') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('customProducts', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('customProducts', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#69 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#71 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#75 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#76 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#77 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#78 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#79 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#80 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#81 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#82 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#83 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#84 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#85 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#86 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#87 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#88 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#89 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#90 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:494]
#91 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#92 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000032fe7c050000000012f0273d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#93 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000032fe7c050000000012f0273d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#94 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000032fe7c050000000012f0273d#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#95 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000032fe7c050000000012f0273d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#96 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000032fe7c050000000012f0273d#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#97 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000032fe7c050000000012f0273d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:140]
#98 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#99 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#100 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000032fe7c070000000012f0273d#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Comment: Can you please look into this file to troubleshoot the issue app/code/Riff/UCW/view/frontend/templates/category/products.phtml

Answer (score 2):

The issue occurs because Magento has a dependency between the modules.
By enabling the following modules, it should work again:

```
bin/magento module:enable Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct
bin/magento module:enable Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct
```

Then:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I get this error after I upgraded Magento from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1. I've fixed it by enabling 2 new Magento modules:

1. Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct
2. Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct

I think that enough to enable one at least. To enable this modules call this commands in console:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct 
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```