# MsrpPriceCalculator exception after upgrade to 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.3.1, msrp

#### Preconditions (*)

After performing an upgrade to the last magento version, I faced the following message:
1. 2.3.0 to 2.3.1

#### Steps to reproduce (*)

1. Perform Magento upgrade from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1

#### Expected result (*)

1. Upgrade occurs normally.
   2.

#### Actual result (*)

1. MsrpPriceCalculator exception

See the full message:

```
{
"0":"Missing required argument $msrpPriceCalculators of Magento\\Msrp\\Pricing\\MsrpPriceCalculator.","1":"<pre>
#1 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Msrp\\Pri...', array(array('msrpPriceCalcula...', NULL, true, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]
#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\Msrp\\Pri...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]
#3 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Msrp\\Pri...') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-msrp\/Helper\/Data.php:82]
#4 Magento\\Msrp\\Helper\\Data->__construct(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Helper\\Context#00000000533b03ea0000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManager#00000000533b03d70000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Msrp\\Model\\Product\\Options\\Proxy#00000000533b07360000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Msrp\\Model\\Msrp#00000000533b07340000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Msrp\\Model\\Config#00000000533b07720000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Directory\\Model\\PriceCurrency#00000000533b01ea0000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor#00000000533b013f0000000034d54959#, NULL) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#5 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Msrp\\Hel...', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Helper\\Context#00000000533b03ea0000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManager#00000000533b03d70000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Msrp\\Model\\Product\\Options\\Proxy#00000000533b07360000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Msrp\\Model\\Msrp#00000000533b07340000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Msrp\\Model\\Config#00000000533b07720000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Directory\\Model\\PriceCurrency#00000000533b01ea0000000034d54959#, &Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductRepository\\Interceptor#00000000533b013f0000000034d54959#, NULL)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:66]
#6 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\Msrp\\Hel...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]
#7 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Msrp\\Hel...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:160]
#8 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\\Msrp\\Hel...'), 'Magento\\Msrp\\Hel...', NULL, 'msrpData', 'Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:246]
#9 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Advanced...', array(array('context', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('cart', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL), array('products', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL), array('catalogConfig', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('session', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('customerSession', 'Magento\\Customer...', true, NULL), array('checkoutSession', 'Magento\\Checkout...', true, NULL), array('checkoutCart', 'Magento\\Checkout...', true, NULL), array('catalogData', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('importFactory', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL), array('stockRegistry', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('stockHelper', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('productFactory', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('quoteItemFactory', 'Magento\\Quote\\Mo...', true, NULL), array('messageManager', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('priceCurrency', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('msrpData', 'Magento\\Msrp\\Hel...', true, NULL), array('groupManagement', 'Magento\\Customer...', true, NULL)), array('cart' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Advanced...'), 'catalogConfig' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Catalog\\...'), 'session' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Customer...'), 'customerSession' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Customer...'), 'checkoutSession' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Checkout...'), 'scopeConfig' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Framewor...'))) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]
#10 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Advanced...', array(array('context', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('cart', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL), array('products', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL), array('catalogConfig', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('session', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('customerSession', 'Magento\\Customer...', true, NULL), array('checkoutSession', 'Magento\\Checkout...', true, NULL), array('checkoutCart', 'Magento\\Checkout...', true, NULL), array('catalogData', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('importFactory', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL), array('stockRegistry', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('stockHelper', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('productFactory', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('quoteItemFactory', 'Magento\\Quote\\Mo...', true, NULL), array('messageManager', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('priceCurrency', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('msrpData', 'Magento\\Msrp\\Hel...', true, NULL), array('groupManagement', 'Magento\\Customer...', true, NULL)), array('cart' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Advanced...'), 'catalogConfig' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Catalog\\...'), 'session' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Customer...'), 'customerSession' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Customer...'), 'checkoutSession' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Checkout...'), 'scopeConfig' => array('instance' => 'Magento\\Framewor...'))) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]
#11 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]
#12 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:160]
#13 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\\Advanced...'), 'Magento\\Advanced...', NULL, 'checkoutData', 'Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:246]
#14 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Advanced...', array(array('cart', 'Magento\\Checkout...', true, NULL), array('messageFactory', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('eventManager', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('checkoutData', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL), array('optionFactory', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('wishlistFactory', 'Magento\\Wishlist...', true, NULL), array('quoteRepository', 'Magento\\Quote\\Ap...', true, NULL), array('storeManager', 'Magento\\Store\\Mo...', true, NULL), array('localeFormat', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('messageManager', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('productTypeConfi...', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('productConfigura...', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('customerSession', 'Magento\\Customer...', true, NULL), array('stockRegistry', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('stockState', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('stockHelper', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('productRepositor...', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('quoteFactory', 'Magento\\Quote\\Mo...', true, NULL), array('itemFailedStatus', NULL, false, 'failed_sku'), array('data', NULL, false, array()), array('serializer', 'Magento\\Framewor...', false, NULL), array('searchCriteriaBu...', 'Magento\\Framewor...', false, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]
#15 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Advanced...', array(array('cart', 'Magento\\Checkout...', true, NULL), array('messageFactory', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('eventManager', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('checkoutData', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL), array('optionFactory', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('wishlistFactory', 'Magento\\Wishlist...', true, NULL), array('quoteRepository', 'Magento\\Quote\\Ap...', true, NULL), array('storeManager', 'Magento\\Store\\Mo...', true, NULL), array('localeFormat', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('messageManager', 'Magento\\Framewor...', true, NULL), array('productTypeConfi...', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('productConfigura...', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('customerSession', 'Magento\\Customer...', true, NULL), array('stockRegistry', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('stockState', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('stockHelper', 'Magento\\CatalogI...', true, NULL), array('productRepositor...', 'Magento\\Catalog\\...', true, NULL), array('quoteFactory', 'Magento\\Quote\\Mo...', true, NULL), array('itemFailedStatus', NULL, false, 'failed_sku'), array('data', NULL, false, array()), array('serializer', 'Magento\\Framewor...', false, NULL), array('searchCriteriaBu...', 'Magento\\Framewor...', false, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]
#16 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]
#17 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:160]
#18 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\\Advanced...'), 'Magento\\Advanced...', NULL, 'cart', 'Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:246]
#19 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Advanced...', array(array('cart', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]
#20 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Advanced...', array(array('cart', 'Magento\\Advanced...', true, NULL)), array()) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]
#21 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]
#22 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/ObserverFactory.php:33]
#23 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\ObserverFactory->get('Magento\\Advanced...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:58]
#24 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch(array('instance' => 'Magento\\Advanced...', 'name' => 'magento_advanced...'), &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#00000000533b07490000000034d54959#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-staging\/Model\/Event\/Manager.php:97]
#25 Magento\\Staging\\Model\\Event\\Manager->dispatch('view_block_abstr...', array('block' => &Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template#00000000533b061e0000000034d54959#)) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Staging\/Model\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php:95]
#26 Magento\\Staging\\Model\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy->dispatch('view_block_abstr...', array('block' => &Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template#00000000533b061e0000000034d54959#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/AbstractBlock.php:653]
#27 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Page.php:249]
#28 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page->render(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000533b02360000000034d54959#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Layout.php:171]
#29 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000533b02360000000034d54959#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]
#30 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000533b02360000000034d54959#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]
#31 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000533b02360000000034d54959#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]
#32 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000533b02360000000034d54959#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php:130]
#33 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000533b02360000000034d54959#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:140]
#34 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]
#35 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:258]
#36 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#00000000533b02340000000034d54959#) called at [index.php:39]
<\/pre>","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

I found the same issue reported by another user here:
[MsrpPriceCalculator Exception](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268064/msrppricecalculator-exception)

Have you guys faced this issue before?

Comment: I've same issue. I founded reason and posted answer on this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268064/msrppricecalculator-exception/273254#273254

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because Magento has a dependency between those modules.
By enabling the following modules, it should work again:

```
bin/magento module:enable Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct
bin/magento module:enable Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct
```

Then:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it works!